# Display data from database into textview

Tags: android, database

I'm trying display random data from database into two textviews (TextView1 display NAME, TextView2 display PHONENUMBER) when I click on next button, but I don't know how can I do it. please help! 
There are some class and xml file I'm using (I referenced at androidhive.info):

```
    public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";

    // Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
     */

    // Adding new contact
    void addContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    // Getting single contact
    Contact getContact(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                KEY_NAME, KEY_PH_NO }, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null,        null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
        // return contact
        return contact;
    }

    // Getting All Contacts
    public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Contact contact = new Contact();
                contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return contactList;
    }

    // Updating single contact
    public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
        values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
    }

    // Deleting single contact
    public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
        db.close();
    }


    // Getting contacts Count
    public int getContactsCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }



   }
```

Contact.java class :

```
    public class Contact {

    //private variables
    int _id;
    String _name;
    String _phone_number;

    // Empty constructor
    public Contact(){

    }
    // constructor
    public Contact(int id, String name, String _phone_number){
        this._id = id;
        this._name = name;
        this._phone_number = _phone_number;
    }

    // constructor
    public Contact(String name, String _phone_number){
        this._name = name;
        this._phone_number = _phone_number;
    }
    // getting ID
    public int getID(){
        return this._id;
    }

    // setting id
    public void setID(int id){
        this._id = id;
    }

    // getting name
    public String getName(){
        return this._name;
    }

    // setting name
    public void setName(String name){
        this._name = name;
    }

    // getting phone number
    public String getPhoneNumber(){
        return this._phone_number;
    }

    // setting phone number
    public void setPhoneNumber(String phone_number){
        this._phone_number = phone_number;
    }
  }
```

AndroidSQLiteTutorialActivity.java class :

```
    public class AndroidSQLiteTutorialActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

        /**
         * CRUD Operations
         * */
        // Inserting Contacts
        Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
        db.addContact(new Contact("Ravi", "9100000000"));
        db.addContact(new Contact("Srinivas", "9199999999"));
        db.addContact(new Contact("Tommy", "9522222222"));
        db.addContact(new Contact("Karthik", "9533333333"));

        // Reading all contacts
        Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
        List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();       

        for (Contact cn : contacts) {
            String log = "Id: "+cn.getID()+" ,Name: " + cn.getName() + " ,Phone: " +    cn.getPhoneNumber();
                // Writing Contacts to log
        Log.d("Name: ", log);

        }
    }
    private void contactList() {
        //set the question text from current question

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

        /**
         * CRUD Operations
         * */
        // Inserting Contacts
        Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
        db.addContact(new Contact("Ravi", "9100000000"));
        db.addContact(new Contact("Srinivas", "9199999999"));
        db.addContact(new Contact("Tommy", "9522222222"));
        db.addContact(new Contact("Karthik", "9533333333"));

        // Reading all contacts
        Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
        List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();       
        TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);


        for (Contact cn : contacts) {
            String name1 = "Id: "+cn.getID()+" ,Name: " + cn.getName() + " ,Phone: " + cn.getPhoneNumber();
                // Writing Contacts to log
        Log.d("Name: ", name1);

        }



    }

}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@android:color/white" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/next"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: There is a lot of code there. What is working so far? What is the exact problem you are stuck on? You need to get the data from the DB. Convert to a String if it isn't already. Then set the text of the TextView` Is any of that working? I may have missed it but I didn't even see the `onClick` listener for your `next` button

Comment: sorry, i don't know how it work so i can't write onClick listener for your next button, :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you will need to set [setOnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29) for button to do some action on Button click  and use and Counter variable to show next value on button click as:

```
List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();   

    TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    Button buttonnext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
    buttonnext.setOnClickListener(onclickListener);
    int listcounter=0;

private OnClickListener onclickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
       if(listcounter<contacts.size()){
          Contact cn=contacts.get(listcounter);

          name.setText("");
          name.append("Id: "+cn.getID());
          name.append(" ,Name: "+cn.getName());
          name.append(",Phone: "+cn.getPhoneNumber());

          listcounter++;
        }
       else{
             //Reset the Counter here
            listcounter = 0;

       }
    }
};
```

Comment: there are have some errors when i put this code in AndroidSQLiteTutorialActivity class:  "String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote"

Comment: @mrZ : k post your new log

Comment: @mrZ : try as `name.setText(cn.getName());` and check value is added in textview or not?

Comment: sorry, it still has problem, could you fix it, please http://www.mediafire.com/?37xvexh8b8fb668

Comment: @mrZ : take your updated or working code from [here](https://sites.google.com/site/imrankhanandroid/TempsqlTestproj.rar?attredirects=0&d=1)

Answer (score 0):

You need an `OnClickListener` in your button. You can declare it in XML using the `android:onClick` attribute.

This is explained in a detailed manner in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#HandlingEvents.

Comment: but what menthod help me take data from database?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    Button buttonnext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
    buttonnext.setOnClickListener(onclickListener);

private OnClickListener onclickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {


int randInt = new Random().nextInt(contacts.size()) + 1;
       Contact cn=contacts.get(randInt);
          name.setText("Id: "+cn.getID()+" ,Name: " + cn.getName() + "
                    ,Phone: " + cn.getPhoneNumber());
    }
};
```

Comment: there are have some errors when i put this code in AndroidSQLiteTutorialActivity class: "String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote"