# Android sqlite database display in textview

Tags: android, sqlite

i have created a simple sqlite database ,it consists of name and two phone numbers corresponding each name.Now i want to display data in text views.Also i have 4 entries of name and phoen number ande i want to display all of them.

Comment: What difficulty are you facing? Please share some code if you have.

Answer (score 2):

Have you search in google before..

O.K

Just visit below link:
[Display data from database into textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179148/display-data-from-database-into-textview)

Regards