# How to retrieve and display data from a database to TextView

Tags: android, sqlite, textview

I've build the code for my database and also the TextView but **(EDITED:)** **I don't know the `STEPS` for how to retrieve data from my database and display them in TextView.**  Generaly to take a picture I save locations from another activity with a map inside my database. Here is my database code:

```
 class MyDatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MapLocations.db";
 private static final String TABLE_LOCATIONS = "Locations";
 private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
 private static final String COLUMN_LOCATIONNAME = "LocationName";

 MyDatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
 }

 @Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOCATIONS + "(" + COLUMN_ID +
            " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_LOCATIONNAME +
            " TEXT" + ");";
    db.execSQL(query);
 }

 @Override
 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + TABLE_LOCATIONS);
    onCreate(db);
 }

 void addLocation(String string) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_LOCATIONNAME, string);
    getWritableDatabase().insert(TABLE_LOCATIONS, null, values);
 }
}
```

And here is my activity with TextView:

```
   public class PreviousLocationsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView textv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_previous_locations);
    textv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dbtextv);
    (????)
}
```

I know it's simple but I need a little help.
I only want to **retrieve** and **display** any data that my database possibly has at TextView.
How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Which part is it that you have trouble with? Are you having trouble querying your database, converting the response to a text, or setting the textview's text?

Comment: [this solution](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/how-to-fetch-data-from-sqlite-database-in-android) might be help full

Comment: Wrong is that you are asking for the code, which means doing your work instead of you. Only you should write a code. We can help you to write it, but not do it instead of you. So if you want some help, please specify what exactly is the problem to `Take data from my database`? Why you can't do it?

Comment: I need the steps sorry the steps or the procedure to do this the code is ok.

Comment: What is wrong with your question is that you are **demanding the complete code**, and seem to have refused to read the tutorial on how to solve this problem yourself.

Comment: I fix this (edited it) now I need only the steps, is it ok now?

Comment: @ArgonOne u have already accepted answer and now editing why? u haven't solve that problem?

Comment: and when you are getting your data?

Comment: See this link [How to retrieve data from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298835/how-to-retrieve-data-from-sqlite-database-in-android-and-display-it-in-textview)

Comment: First of all, none of the people downvoting you answer Stack Overflow questions for a living, so professionalism doesn't enter into it. Second, you have been linked to at least two step-by-step guides and two Stack Overflow questions and none of your edits explains why these don't answer your question.

Comment: Well first of all `Display data from database into textview` is unclear and hasn't got a specific answer, secondly I know that my problem can be solved with 3 lines of code (until now I know only the second one) and `https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/` has over 100 lines of code! Where I can look for my answer? Anyway until now I have learn how to display my data But I still do not know how to retrieve the data from a database.

Comment: The link you mentioned has a step-by-step explanation for the DatabaseHelper code, and the biggest lump of code is just a repetition of all the code written so far. You can just skim over the bolded parts until you see something relevant, such as a reference to reading, and then skip the steps you aren't looking for, and maybe backtrack once or twice to find the preliminary steps you needed.

Answer (score 0):

**I only want to display any data that my database possibly has at TextView** to display data you can use `textv.setText("Your data will be here");` for your data base you can see this referenced link [Display data from database into textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179148/display-data-from-database-into-textview)

Comment: Yes but how to take the data from my database?

Comment: first open the database, fetch the data and close the data base go through this link [Click Me](http://whats-online.info/science-and-tutorials/127/Android-SQLite-database-step-by-step-tutorial-for-beginners/) and to retrieve data [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298835/how-to-retrieve-data-from-sqlite-database-in-android-and-display-it-in-textview)

Answer (score 0):

get data from database first.

then textv.setText("text");

Please check the link.
https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/